# Are recursive calls to performBlockAndWait: allowed?

Tags: ios, core-data

Context: Using Core Data, I have a main context on a private queue (that I will call `mainContext`), and another context on the main queue, child of the main (that I will call `childContext`). The queues does not matter, the answer to my question should not depend on the queues the contexts are on.

My goal is to save `childContext`’s modifications to the disk directly without letting a chance for `mainContext` to have any modifications before the modifications brought by `childContext` are saved to the disk.

In order to do that, I call:

```
[self.childContext performBlockAndWait:^{
  [self.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    [self.childContext save:NULL];
    [self.parentContext save:NULL];
  }];
}];
```

The idea behind that being that if I perform a block and wait on the child and parent contexts at the same time, there cannot be any modifications on the main context while the child is saved. Then the main context is saved, and we exit the blocks. The doc clearly states that calls to `performBlockAndSave:` are re-entrant, so this should work.

Does it? Are nested calls to `performBlockAndWait:` valid? Apparently, the saves are done both on the `mainContext`’s queue, and the `childContext`’s queue is not locked during the saves. Is it normal? If so, how can I achieve my goal?

---

*Note*: I need this atomicity because of the way I communicate with my API. To create an object on my API, I create the object locally, then I check the local modifications on the Core Data context, and convert these modifications into API calls. If I called:

```
[self.childContext performBlockAndWait:^{
  [self.childContext save:NULL];
  /* 1 */
  [self.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    [self.parentContext save:NULL];
  }];
}];
```

there would be a possibility for a `performBlock:` on the `mainContext` to be called just before the `performBlockAndWait:` saving the `mainContext` (at `1`). This call would have an "unclean" context, with the changes from the `childContext` waiting to be saved on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to just create more child contexts further down the context hierarchy.

Please allow me to to re-name your contexts for clarity:

Let's call the `mainContext` the **`rootContext`** (background, saving to persistent store).
Let's call the `childContext` the **`mainContext`** (main thread context, child of `rootContext`).
Let's call any lower child context a **"worker context"** (background, child of `mainContext`).

The worker contexts should be background contexts with the main context as the parent.

You can have a central place where the root context does the save to the physical store, e.g. where you manage your Core Data stack.

As I understand it, when changes are pushed from the worker context to the main context via `save:` and at the same time that main context is itself pushing up changes to its parent context in a `performBlockAndWait` block, it will only get the changes once it is finished. Only then can it push them up further to the root context to be physically saved. I think that should accomplish your atomicity goals.

By introducing the worker contexts you are making sure that the root context does not receive any updates from anywhere else but the main context.

Comment: This comes close to a solution I thought of once. I'll give it another go and accept your answer if everything goes well.